# Memory overflow in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
   int n, cont, fib, na = 0, nb = 1, sum_even = 0;
   printf ("Insert a number and I'll tell you the respective Fibonacci: ");
   scanf ("%d", &n);
   for (cont = 1; cont < n; cont++) {
      na += nb;
      nb = na - nb;
      fib = na + nb;
      if (fib % 2 == 0) {
         sum_even += fib;
      }
   }
   printf ("%d\n", sum_even);
   return 0;
}
```

I was trying to do the Project Euler [Problem 2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2), and then I came up with this code. The problem is: I can't find the sum of the pair numbers on fibonacci's sequence for numbers over 400 or something near that, because memory overflows. In consequence, I cant solve the exercise, since it asks to find the sum of the pair numbers below 4000000 in fibonacci's sequence. Can anyone help me?

Edit:
I tried to used float type numbers to increase the answer's capacity, it seems to work till a thousand or so, but if I try with bigger numbers, I get a -nan error in bash after like 15 secs of processing (I don't really know what it means).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
   int n, cont, div;
   float sum_even = 0, na = 0, nb = 1, fib;
   printf ("Insert a number and I'll tell you the respective Fibonacci: ");
   scanf ("%d", &n);
   for (cont = 1; cont <= n; cont++) {
      na += nb;
      nb = na - nb;
      fib = na + nb;
      div = fib / 2;
      if (div % 2 == 0) {
         sum_even += fib;
      }
   }
   printf ("%f\n", sum_even);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the problem statement. The task is to find the sum of

```
{ fib(n) : fib(n) <= 4000000 && fib(n) % 2 == 0 }
```

and not

```
{ fib(n) : n <= 4000000 && fib(n) % 2 == 0 }
```

That task is solved without problems with a minor modification to your code. Instead of

```
for (cont = 1; cont < n; cont++) {
```

use

```
while(fib <= n) {
```

Comment: Yes. I was answering the same. Maybe long instead a int is needed however.

Comment: Not necessary here, `fib(34) = 5702887 > 4000000`, so the sum easily fits into 32-bit `int`s. There are a lot of problems later on where you need 64-bit integers.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand my mistake. Anyway I'm going to take a look at these long int, double and stuff. I'm still very new to programming, so I don't know much at all.

Answer (score 15):

What you observe is not a memory overflow, it is a numeric overflow. The whole point of the exercise was to show that overflow does happen, and make you learn techniques to deal with it. In this particular case, they expect you to either implement [arbitrary precision integer arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), or borrow a pre-made implementation and use it with your solution.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/91YHNJyT
I tried to use float type numbers to increaase their capacity, it seems to work till 600 or so, but if I try 4000000, after like 15 seconds, I get a -nan error in bash. (I don't really know what it means).

Comment: The idea is to use something much bigger than `float`, `long long`, `double`, or even `uint128_t`. You need a lot more digits than you can fit into 128 bits. You can try [CLN](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/), or implement your own addition/subtraction of very long integers encoded, for example, as arrays of their decimal digits.